# Liberar option de un select cuando cambia

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tengo siguiente código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Documento sin título</title>    
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            $prueba = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18);

            for ($i = 1; $i <= 18; $i++):?>
                <label>opcion <?php echo $i;?></label>
                <select class="hola">
                    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Selecciona uno</option>
                    <?php foreach($prueba as $elemento):?>
                        <option><?php echo $elemento?></option>
                    <?php endforeach?>
                </select>
                <br>
                <br>
            <?php endfor?>

        <script> 
            $('.hola').change(function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $(this)
                    .siblings('select')
                    .children('option')
                    .each(function() {
                        if ( $(this).text() === value ) {
                            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings();   
                        }
                    });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hace parte de lo que quiero, cuando marco una opción en un `select`, la misma se anula en el resto de `select`, porque no se puede repetir. El problema viene cuando cambio la opción de algún `select`, porque necesito que esa opción se libere en el resto de `select` para que pueda ser seleccionada de nuevo.

**EDICIÓN:**

Edito la pregunta y gracias @C.Rodriguez porque funciona perfectamente el código, pero tengo el problema que cuando lo introduzco dentro de una tabla, donde las filas se generan con el bucle `for` ya no funciona, y no veo por qué.

Añado el código con el `select` dentro de la tabla:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Documento sin título</title>
        <script src="js/jQuery341.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $prueba = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18);
        ?>  

        <table style="border:solid 2px #000000;">
            <tr>
                <th>Opcion</th>
            </tr>   
            <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 18; $i++):?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="opcion<?php echo $i?>" class="hola" required="required">
                            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Selecciona uno</option>
                            <?php foreach($prueba as $elemento):?>
                                <option><?php echo $elemento?></option>
                            <?php endforeach?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>        
            <?php endfor?> 
        </table>

        <script>
            $('.hola').change(function() {

                // En caso de que la opción 'Selecciona uno' esté seleccionada, retornará 'undefined',
                // De esta manera se evitará bloquear la opción 'Selecciona uno'.
                var values = $("table.hola option:selected").toArray().map((option) => {
                    var value = $(option).val();            
                    /*return value === "Selecciona uno" ? undefined : value;*/
                    return $(option).val();
                });

                $(this)
                    .siblings('select')
                    .children('option')
                    .attr("disabled", false);

                $(this)
                    .siblings('select')
                    .children('option')
                    .each(function () {
                        // Busca si el valor del option actual coincide con algún valor en el array anterior
                        var disable = values.find(value => {
                            return $(this).text() === value;
                        });

                        // Deshabilita la opción si 'disable' es true
                        if (disable) {
                            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings();
                        }
                    });        
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDICIÓN 2:**

Añado el nuevo código con el `input type="text"` y el `datalist`, por cierto, el código me da un error en esta línea, el editor es dreamweaver:

```
var values = $('datalist option:selected').toArray().map((option) => {
```

El código con el `input` y el `datalist` y los cambios que me han sugerido son:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Documento sin título</title>
        <script src="js/jQuery341.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $prueba = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18);
        ?>      
        <table style="border:solid 2px #000000;">
            <tr>
                <th>Opcion</th>
            </tr>   
            <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 18; $i++):?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" list="lista" name="opcion<?php echo $i?>" class="hola" required="required" placeholder="Selecciona uno">
                        <datalist id="lista">
                            <?php foreach($prueba as $elemento):?>
                                <option><?php echo $elemento?></option>
                            <?php endforeach?>
                        </datalist>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endfor?> 
        </table>

        <script>
            $('.hola').change(function() {

                // En caso de que la opción 'Selecciona uno' esté seleccionada, retornará 'undefined',
                // De esta manera se evitará bloquear la opción 'Selecciona uno'.
                var values = $('datalist option:selected').toArray().map((option) => {
                    var value = $(option).val();

                    /*return value === "Selecciona uno" ? undefined : value;*/
                    return $(option).val();
                });

                $('datalist')
                    .children('option')
                    .attr("disabled", false);

                $('datalist')
                    .children('option')
                    .each(function () {
                        // Busca si el valor del option actual coincide con algún valor en el array anterior
                        var disable = values.find(value => {
                            return $(this).text() === value;
                        });

                        // Deshabilita la opción si 'disable' es true
                        if (disable) {
                            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings();
                        }
                    });

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Perti. Bienvenido a SOes. Solo como recomendación, SO funciona de manera que haces una pregunta específica y la misma es respondida, no funciona como un foro. Por lo tanto, si una respuesta responde a tu pregunta específica pero una vez que la aplicas te aparece un nuevo problema o duda (por ejemplo, quieres aplicar la misma solución con una tabla o usando `datalist` e `inputs`), en vez de añadir una edición describiendo el nuevo problema, lo más recomendable sería que crearas una nueva pregunta con tu nueva duda haciendo referencia en la misma a la pregunta anterior.

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo una solución alternativa muy similar a la que te ha dado @C.Rodriguez, el problema no es tanto que deshabilites las opciones en todos los `select` incluyendo las que están en el que has variado, sino que tienes que volver a restablecer las opciones que no estén seleccionadas para que no permanezcan deshabilitadas, te lo explico más detenidamente. Teniendo en cuenta el siguiente `HTML` de ejemplo:

```
<div class="contenedor">
    <select>
        <option value="">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="option1">Opción 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Opción 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Opción 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Opción 4</option>
        <option value="option5">Opción 5</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option value="">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="option1">Opción 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Opción 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Opción 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Opción 4</option>
        <option value="option5">Opción 5</option>
        <option value="option6">Opción 6</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option value="">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="option1">Opción 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Opción 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Opción 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Opción 4</option>
        <option value="option5">Opción 5</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Y las siguientes variables:

```
const $contenedor = $('.contenedor');
const $selects = $contenedor.find('select');
const $options = $contenedor.find('select option');
```

Al inicio de la aplicación podrías crear un objeto con los valores únicos contenidos en todas las opciones de los `select`, asignando a los mismos un valor `boolean`:

```
const data = $options.toArray().reduce((obj, option) => (option.value && (obj[option.value] = obj[option.value] || option.selected), obj), {});
```

Esto crearía un objeto como el siguiente:

```
{
    "option1": false,
    "option2": false,
    "option3": false,
    "option4": false,
    "option5": false,
    "option6": false
}
```

Más tarde podrías tener una función que *reseteara* todos los valores dentro del objeto a `false` y después recorriera todos los `selects` y tomando en cuenta la propiedad `value` de cada uno, actualizara los valores que se encuentren dentro del objeto a `true`:

```
function updateData() {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(value => data[value] = false);
    $selects.each((index, el) => (el.value !== "" && (data[el.value] = true)));
};
```

Y ya solo tendrías que llamar a esa función cada vez que se variara un `select` y después actualizar la propiedad `disabled` de cada opción teniendo en cuenta el valor que tiene dentro del objeto. Aquí te dejo un *snippet* con un ejemplo funcional:

```js
const $contenedor = $('.contenedor');
const $selects = $contenedor.find('select');
const $options = $contenedor.find('select option');

const data = $options.toArray().reduce((obj, option) => (option.value && (obj[option.value] = obj[option.value] || option.selected), obj), {});

function updateData() {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(value => data[value] = false);
  $selects.each((index, el) => (el.value !== "" && (data[el.value] = true)));
};

$contenedor.on('change', 'select', () => {
  updateData();
  $options.each((index, el) => (el.value !== "" && !el.selected && (el.disabled = data[el.value]), true));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="contenedor">
  <select>
    <option value="">Selecciona</option>
    <option value="option1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Opción 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Opción 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Opción 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Opción 5</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value="">Selecciona</option>
    <option value="option1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Opción 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Opción 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Opción 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Opción 5</option>
    <option value="option6">Opción 6</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value="">Selecciona</option>
    <option value="option1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Opción 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Opción 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Opción 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Opción 5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que está sucediendo es que cada vez que cambias el valor de un `<select>` deshabilitas la opción seleccionada en todos los `<select>` que se encuentren, sin embargo, lo que debería suceder es:

- Obtener todos los valores de las opciones seleccionadas (un array de valores).
- Habilitar TODAS las opciones existentes (esto reiniciará el atributo `disabled` de todas las opciones de los `<select>`).
- Buscar en todas las opciones existentes las opciones que ya están seleccionadas y deshabilitarlas.

Para realizar lo mencionado anteriormente, nos enfocaremos en tu `script`

---

**PASO 1:** Obtener todos los valores de las opciones seleccionadas (un array de valores).

```
// En caso de que la opción 'Selecciona uno' esté seleccionada, retornará 'undefined',
// De esta manera se evitará bloquear la opción 'Selecciona uno'.
var values = $(".hola option:selected").toArray().map((option) => { 
    var value = $(option).val();
    return value === "Selecciona uno" ? undefined : value;
});
```

Básicamente, consiste en seleccionar todas los `<select>` que existen y obtener su valor seleccionado, por defecto, se toma el valor `Selecciona uno`, sin embargo, esto implica que también se deshabilitará, para evitar esto se utiliza un `if` que retornará `undefined` si dicho valor está seleccionado, caso contrario retornará el valor seleccionado.

Si necesitas que `Selecciona uno` siempre esté deshabilitado, entonces simplemente tendrías que eliminar ese `if` y dejar el value.

```
return $(option).val();
```

---

**PASO 2:** Habilitar TODAS las opciones existentes (esto reiniciará el atributo `disabled` de todas las opciones de los `<select>`).

```
$('select.hola').children('option').attr("disabled", false);
```

De esta manera, todos las opciones quedarán habilitadas para después deshabilitar los nuevos valores.

---

**PASO 3:** Buscar en todas las opciones existentes las opciones que ya están seleccionadas y deshabilitarlas.

```
$('select.hola').children('option').each(function () {
    // Busca si el valor del option actual coincide con algún valor en el array anterior
    var disable = values.find(value => {
        return $(this).text() === value;
    });

    // Deshabilita la opción si 'disable' es true
    if (disable) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings();
    }
});
```

Finalmente, las opciones que coincidan quedarán deshabilitadas.

---

**EDIT:**

Para que funcione (y para evitar futuros inconvenientes si necesitas cambiar y/o agregar más código HTML), lo que debes hacer es modificar los 'selectores' para el `<select>` (ya que modificaste la estructura). Cambiar:

```
$(this).siblings('select').children('option').attr("disabled", false);
$(this).siblings('select').children('option').each(function () {...
```

Por esto:

```
$('select.hola').children('option').attr("disabled", false);
$('select.hola').children('option').each(function () {...
```

(Ya actualicé código).

---

**EDIT 2:**

Con base en tu nueva estructura y acorde al comentario que te hice, es necesario hacer las respectivas modificaciones, tu código javascript debería verse así:

```
$('.hola').change(function () {

    // Retorna un array con cada valor seleccionado en los 'input'
    var values = $(".hola").toArray().map((input) => { 
        return $(input).val();
    }); 

    // Habilita todas las opciones del datalist (las que estaban deshabilitadas)
    $('#lista').children('option').attr("disabled", false);

    // Recorre todas las opciones del datalist
    $('#lista').children('option').each(function () {

        // Busca si el valor del option actual coincide con algún valor en el array anterior
        var disable = values.find(value => {
            return $(this).text() === value;
        });

        // Deshabilita la opción si 'disable' es true
        if (disable) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funciona perfectamente así como esta, pero si meto el 'select' en una tabla ya no funciona, y no entiendo porque. Edito la pregunta con el código dentro de la tabla para ver si me puedes echar una mano porque no entiendo porque no funciona. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Revisa el **EDIT** en la respuesta

Comment: Eres una maquina, muchas gracias. Solo me queda una ultima duda que si me la pudieras resolver. Si en lugar de ser con un select fuera con un input type=text que incorpora una datalist para seleccionar?? El selecciona uno lo tengo como placeholder. Otra vez muchísimas gracias.

Comment: En ese caso, dependerá de cómo lo estés realizando, pero en buena teoría sólo tendrías que cambiar `$('.hola option:selected')` y `$('select.hola')` por `$('datalist option:selected')` y `$('datalist')`, respectivamente. De igual forma, tendrías que revisar y analizar que tu código siga optimizado.

Comment: Buenas C.Rodríguez, no me funciona, edito la pregunta añadiendo como sería el código a ver si ves el problema. Mucas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Hola @Perti, revisa el **EDIT 2**. Además, tal vez podamos ayudarte si proporcionas más información sobre el error que te muestra Dreamweaver